# I am having an issue with this shortcode plugin.. Warning: Illegal string offset 'title'

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings, shortcode

I have a wordpress site and I am using a plugin that uses shortcode as a widget to pull recent blog posts.  In the column I am getting an error that reads:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in /home3/xxxxx/xxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/recent-blogs-shortcode/recent-blogs-shortcode.php on line 44

So the Title would be the blog post title, but I am just having trouble on how to fix it.

add_shortcode( 'recent-blogs', 'cp_sidebar_recent_blogs_shortcode');

```
function cp_sidebar_recent_blogs_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // shortcode_atts will only allow us to supply 1 default; for the horizontal layout submitted with no title, use a different default
    $title_default = '';
    if ($atts['title'] == 'Related Posts' && $atts['layout'] == 'horizontal' ) {
        $title_default = 'Related Posts';
    }
    else {
        $title_default = 'Recent Posts';
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description on the error you face, Just code alone will not help. A small paragraph on the error, what output you get and what is expected would make things easier.

Comment: @nxn Thank you, this is my first post, I fixed it, could you tell me if that is better or do I need more information.  Any feedback you provide me is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your `$atts` variable is actually an array. The error you are getting is because you are trying to reference array keys `$atts['title']` and `$atts['layout']` of a non array variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  I am in the process of learning this.. So I apologize if I'm such a novice..  So my first stupid question is where would I check that?  Myphpadmin?

Comment: http://www.zeph.doctoraffordable.com/zephyrhills-fl/primary-care/